# Check if the countdown timer is 0

Tags: c#, if-statement, timer, timespan

I have a script based on the countdown timer. I want that when the time reaches 0, the timer stop and a message appear. The code id this:

```
public partial class simulare : Form
    {
        private admin admin;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        public simulare(admin admin)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.admin=admin;
            label2.Text = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.1).ToString();
        }
        private void simulare_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var startTime = DateTime.Now;
            timer = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 };
            timer.Tick += (obj, args) =>
            label2.Text = (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.1) - (DateTime.Now - startTime)).ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();
            if (condition)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Done!");
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried those conditions, but unsuccessful:

```
if (timer.ToString() == TimeSpan.Zero.ToString())

if (label2.Text.ToString() == TimeSpan.Zero.ToString())

if (label2.Text == TimeSpan.Zero)
```

Comment: why are you `newing` the instance of Timer Twice..? `Timer timer = new Timer();` change the one outside the Method to this 
`Timer timer;`for readability it makes it easier to follow... also have you debugged the code..?

Comment: what does `when the time reaches 0` mean to you?  The timer is ticking every second and updating the label.

Comment: Yes. If I use `if(timer.ToString() == TimeSpan.Zero.ToStrin())` as condition, error is this: `The thread 0x17a4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).`

Comment: Reaches 0 = time is 00:00:00; 0 h, 0 m, 0 s

Comment: `timer.ToString()` yields something tlike this: `"System.Windows.Forms.Timer, Interval: 100"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the calculation and assign the result to a TimeSpan variable, then check if the Seconds in that TimeSpan variable are equals to zero

```
void simulare_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 1000 };
    timer.Tick += (obj, args) =>
    {
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.1) - (DateTime.Now - startTime);
        label1.Text = ts.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
        if (ts.Seconds == 0)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Done!");
        }
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, checking *anything* in the `Load` event isn't going to work. That code only runs once (on form load).

So you need a more complex tick event, which I would put into an actual function instead of a lambda:

```
private int countDown = 50; //Or initialize at load time, or whatever
public void TimerTick(...)
{
    label2.Text = (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.1) - (DateTime.Now - startTime)).ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
    countDown--;

    if (countDown <= 0)
       timer.Stop();
}
```

I use an `int` counter here since checking against a view property (the text in this case) isn't a very good design/practice. If you really want a `TimeSpan`, I would still save it off instead of checking directly against the `Text` property or a string.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I kinda understand what you say, but ok, I use that function, but in Load what should I put near timer.Start() ?

Comment: @Paulicaaa Just assign the tick event to this function, and get rid of the useless condition. In other words, just set up and start the timer. Nothing fancy necessary.